# Enforce explicit type arguments

Tags: f#, inline

I have a generic function where it's easy to get the compiler to infer the wrong type parameters. The type parameters only control the return type, and if I accidentally miss off a type annotation, the compiler infers `obj`.

How can I make it a compile-time error to call my function without giving it explicit type parameters? The `Unchecked.defaultof` function works the way I'd like:

```
> Unchecked.defaultof;;

  Unchecked.defaultof;;
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

stdin(1,1): error FS0685: The generic function 'defaultof' must be given explicit type argument(s)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `defaultof` function uses a special attribute. The F# source code is, once again, useful. The implementation of the function is in `prim-types.fs`, but the attribute is added in the interface file `prim-types.fsi`. A combined declaration would be:

```
[<RequiresExplicitTypeArguments>] 
let inline unsafeDefault<'T> : 'T = (# "ilzero !0" type ('T) : 'T #)
```

The inline IL `(# ... #)` is limited to F# core, but the declaration is something anybody can use.

You can find the attribute in section 16 (page 217) of the [F# specification](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.pdf):

> When applied to an F# function or method, indicates that the function or method must be given explicit type arguments when used. For example, `typeof<int>`.
>   This attribute should be used only in F# assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Tomas - I was looking at the implementation in prim-types.fs, not at the signature in prim-types.fsi.

Comment: @Tim - I was looking into the `fs` file first as well. It took me some time to figure out that it can actually be in `fsi` file :-)

Answer (score 7):

[RequiresExplicitTypeArgumentsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340327.aspx) should help